# Why simulator rotates from landscape to portrait when playing video

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I start my application in landscape on my simulator. But when I start playing video, simulator rotates in portrait(the video is for landscape), then go back to the menu and simulator is again in landscape. So how to fix rotating of simulator ? Is this a simulator bug ?

Comment: can you post some code for reference so that we can help

Comment: are you using MPMoviePlayerController or are we actually talking about a web view embedded playback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no sir no bug, that is the default made for playing the video.

Comment: hm.. Then I can do nothing with it (. Wanted to make a demo video of my application in landscape and this rotation won't look very nice.